# SSRS Ordering issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-order-by, ssrs-2012

I have a column thats ordered correctly in SQL SERVER IN DESC order as expected but as soon as i import it to SSRS the order is correct for all rows apart from one.

Below is the sql server result:

```
    Figure
    2.5000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
   -8.0000
   -27.000
   -93.550
```

This is the SSRS report result:

```
    Figure
    2.5000
    0.0000
   -8.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
   -27.000
   -93.550
```

I have tried lots of different things to try and rectify the issue but i just cant see what the problem is.
I havent altered the code in anyway between SQL server and SSRS so i dont know why this would happen. I thought it may be grouping that was happening in SSRS but when i removed everything and just had the original columned data it still did it.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually discovered to issue in SSRS. Basically if you have groups, SSRS automatically puts a sorting filter on all of them. If you go to the bottom:

[image]

Click the dropdown and then go on group properties. If you look at the sorting tab make sure you remove the sorting filter. You will need to repeat this for every group in every table/matrix you have.

Then any SQL sorting code you have should display the results correctly. The SSRS automatic filter just messes with it. This was mentioned briefly in the answer above but here is the exact process. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I see that you tried recreating, but the default should be ascending order.

Check the datatype of the column.

Also, try editing/adding the sort expression in the tablix (Properties -> sorting). Also check the group sorting, it could be there.

Comment: If you have checked the datatype, I would start fresh with a new report and make a limited version of this, just to try and duplicate it. Also, is it a select or an SP that is the source?

Comment: PS It could very well be an SSRS bug. Did you try setting the datatype and manual sort?

Comment: Also, do a View Code and look at the actual definition! It could be that you can see why the sorting is wrong in the source code of the report.

Comment: Have you got any more information i can look at? I really dont understand any of that

Comment: Sure! If you want to view the report source code open the report in VS, then do View->Code, then search for 'sort' and 'order'. Perhaps you can find a clue there. Also you could try with a new report from scratch.

Comment: It's not a ready solution, but we would need more info for that.